# Find all simple cycles through a given node in Neo4j

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

I'm working with graphs and recently knew about [neo4j](https://neo4j).

Can neo4j help me to find all simple cycles that go through a given node in a graph?

I already can do this in `java`/`python` code by implementing [a modification of Johnson's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60395/find-all-cycles-through-a-given-vertex).

This is just an example of a graph I created, is Cypher code that can be executed on a neo4j database:

```
CREATE (John:Person { name : '@john',facebook: 'facebook.com/john'})
CREATE (Josh:Person { name : '@josh',facebook: 'facebook.com/josh'})
CREATE (Dan:Person { name : '@dan',facebook: 'facebook.com/dan'})
CREATE (Kenny:Person { name : '@kenny',facebook: 'facebook.com/kenny'})
CREATE (Bart:Person { name : '@bart',facebook: 'facebook.com/bart'})
CREATE (Mike:Person { name : '@mike',facebook: 'facebook.com/mike'})
CREATE (Jenny:Person { name : '@jenny',facebook: 'facebook.com/jenny'})
CREATE (Frank:Person { name : '@frank',facebook: 'facebook.com/frank'})
CREATE (Erick:Person { name : '@erick',facebook: 'facebook.com/erick'})
CREATE (Lynda:Person { name : '@lynda',facebook: 'facebook.com/lynda'})

CREATE (Lynda)-[:KNOWS]-> (Josh)
CREATE (Lynda)-[:KNOWS]-> (Frank)
CREATE (Lynda)-[:KNOWS]-> (Bart)
CREATE (Josh)-[:KNOWS]-> (Erick)
CREATE (Josh)-[:KNOWS]-> (Jenny)
CREATE (Josh)-[:KNOWS]-> (Dan)
CREATE (Dan)-[:KNOWS]-> (Lynda)
CREATE (Dan)-[:KNOWS]-> (Josh)
CREATE (Dan)-[:KNOWS]-> (Mike)
CREATE (Dan)-[:KNOWS]-> (Kenny)
CREATE (Mike)-[:KNOWS]-> (Kenny)
CREATE (Kenny)-[:KNOWS]-> (Bart)
CREATE (Bart)-[:KNOWS]-> (Josh)
CREATE (Frank)-[:KNOWS]-> (Erick)
CREATE (Erick)-[:KNOWS]-> (Frank)
```

...and these are all the cycles within the graph:

```
Josh->Dan->Lynda->Josh
Josh->Dan->Lynda->Bart->Josh
Josh->Dan->Josh
Josh->Dan->Mike->Kenny->Bart->Josh
Josh->Dan->Kenny->Bart->Josh
```

Here a list of simple test cases:

```
1- input: Josh
   output (all the cycles):
    Josh->Dan->Lynda->Josh
    Josh->Dan->Lynda->Bart->Josh
    Josh->Dan->Josh
    Josh->Dan->Mike->Kenny->Bart->Josh
    Josh->Dan->Kenny->Bart->Josh
2- input: Lynda
   output:
    Josh->Dan->Lynda->Josh
    Josh->Dan->Lynda->Bart->Josh
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in Cypher with the following query :

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]->(n) RETURN nodes(p)
```

A textual representation of the query is :

Find me paths where the start node and end node are the same and the complete path has an outgoing direction

Note that this is an expensive query on medium/large graphs, you can limit the depth of the path, for ex :

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*1..15]->(n) RETURN nodes(p)
```

Maybe you want also to have a minimum depth 2, because a node having a relationship to itself will be returned with a depth of 1 ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Christophe! The depth limit you pointed is an amazing extra bonus!

Comment: After analyzing the results, the query takes into account duplicate nodes. How can I modify the query so I can remove those duplicate nodes in the path?